# How to group second word of any line and replace them separately

Tags: regex-group

how can I replace first word of each line which starts with ("w" "b) to ("white" "black")
and the second words all that has "K" "Q" "B"  to "king""Queen""Bishop"

For example below is my text

wk

wQ

wB

wR

wN

wP

bk

bQ

bB

bR

bN

bP

Output should be

White King

White Queen

White Bishop

White Rook

White Knight

White Pawn

&

Black King

Black Queen

Black Bishop

Black Rook

Black Knight

Black Pawn

Until end.

I believe it'l be possible,

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Regex is only for matching, so you're going to have to specify where you want the output to happen. Python, Javascript, CLI…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with Notepad++, using conditional replacement:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:(w)|(b))(?:(k)|(q)|(b)|(r)|(n)|(p))`
- Replace with: `(?1White:Black) (?3King:(?4Queen:(?5Bishop:(?6Rook:(?7Knight:Pawn)))))`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    (w)         # group 1, letter w
  |           # OR
    (b)         # group 2, letter b
)           # end group
(?:         # non capture group
    (k)         # group 3, letter k
  |           # OR
    (q)         # group 3, letter q
  |           # OR
    (b)         # group 3, letter b
  |           # OR
    (r)         # group 3, letter r
  |           # OR
    (n)         # group 3, letter n
  |           # OR
    (p)         # group 3, letter p
)           # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists (i.e. letter w),
  White       # put the word White
:           # else
  Black       # Black
)
 
(?3         # if group 3 exists (letter k)
  King        # then King
:           # else
  (?4         # if group 4 exists (letter q)
    Queen       # then Queen
  :           # else
    (?5         # if group 5 exists
      Bishop      ### and so on...
    :
      (?6
        Rook
      :
        (?7
          Knight
        :
          Pawn
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `([wb])([KQBRNP])` regex in https://regex101.com
2. Click on `TOOLS` subpanel `Code Generator` for generate code in your language.
3. Also read about  a `replace` or similar function which can help you modify string by regex.

Maybe you don't need regulars if you can do something like that in your language:

```js
const convert = (word) => { 
  const a = {"W": "White", "B": "Black"}[word[0].toUpperCase()]
  const b = {"K": "King",  "Q": "Queen",
             "B": "Bishop","R": "Rook",
             "N": "Knight","P": "Pawn"}[word[1].toUpperCase()]
  return a + " " + b 
}

console.log(convert("wk"))
console.log(convert("wQ"))
console.log(convert("wB"))
console.log(convert("wR"))
console.log(convert("wN"))
console.log(convert("wP"))
console.log(convert("bk"))
console.log(convert("bQ"))
console.log(convert("bB"))
console.log(convert("bR"))
console.log(convert("bN"))
console.log(convert("bP"))
```

If you want convert a file and you have `python` installed:

1. write file `conv.py`:

   import re;
   tokens = re.compile(r'^[wb][kQBRNP]$')
   def convert (line):
   if (not tokens.match(line)): return line + '\n';
   a = {"W": "White", "B": "Black"}[line[0].upper()]
   b = {"K": "King",  "Q": "Queen",
   "B": "Bishop","R": "Rook",
   "N": "Knight","P": "Pawn"}[line[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kZwN.png).upper()]
   return f'{a} {b}'
   with open('result.txt', 'w') as writer:
   with open('test.txt') as reader:
   line = reader.readline()
   lines = []
   while(line):
   writer.write(convert(line))
   line = reader.readline()
2. create copy of your file as `test.txt`
3. run: `python conv.py`
4. you'll get `result.txt`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you daniil,  I want to see if this is possible only with regex  find and replace?

Comment: Do you mean C# Regex `regex.Replace(s, target);` ?

Comment: With this regex I can only change the first line but not the rest ... find:  (^w)(k)    replace:  $1hite $2ing ,,,,, making two groups.

Comment: your language is C# ?

Comment: where do you type it ? there is not regex replace, `regex` is a sequence of characters that define a search pattern.

Comment: if you asked about Sublime or other editor I think you can't do replace text using only regex, as you want.

Comment: I have the above text opened in my notepad which supports regular expression,  I want to see if it is possible to change it with (find and replace) syntax of regex ...

Comment: I think it's not possible in notepad, you need a script

Comment: I added script to answer.

Comment: I firstly appreciate your efforts and time,  but I'm totally new with coding,  well I created two files in one folder, firsy my text as test.txt and 2nd File of your code as conv.py  and just installed an IDE program which support 45 languages including python 2.7 and Python 3.6.9 versions from appstore, 
And  run your file with, 
And as a result I got this error, -------  "328042045/source.py", line 9
    return f'{a} {b}' 
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: ок just rewrite it as: `a + " " + b`

Comment: Sorry I think I'm new again error               File "1855341985/source.py", line 9
    return f a + " " + b
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: all line is `return a + " " + b`  without `f`

Comment: `f'{a} {b}'` is equal `a + " " + b`

Comment: what is your OS and where is your file ? you must have permisions to write file

Comment: May be because of android ... your code may work in window,  check them their,, here again error ----------------Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "93100675/source.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as writer:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'result.txt'

Error :

Comment: My OS is android lollipop,   and both test.txt and conv.py are located in ----- storage/emulated/0

Comment: do you have external SD card ? try run code there

Comment: No I'm runing your code in --- (Progman: Learn to Code for free)
By Wish Media  installed from playstore

Comment: No external SD card, sir,________I have to close my question,

Comment: is your question a task from `Learn to Code` ?

Comment: Didn't understand it?

Comment: You can run my code on PC оr Laptop because Android has restrictions on user rights

Comment: Yes true, because my device isn't rooted ______ it may work with unrooted device ...but with every supported language it can write, hello world, with no error